# curriable function that returns a function in scala via '=>', and (secondly), via 1 arg list followed by another

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, currying

I'm starting to learn a little Scala, and I basically 
understand functions that return functions and currying, but 
I've seen  two syntaxes for doing this, and I'd like to better 
understand the differences, and maybe a little of theory behind
what's going on.

In the first method (using `=>`) I can curry the function by just specifying
the argument to be bound to variable `x`.  However when I try to do this
with the second approach, the compiler tells me I need to specify the `_`
wild card for the second argument.

I understand what I need to do but I am not sure why I need to do 
things this way.  Can someone please tell me what the Scala compiler is 
doing here?

First Method using `=>`

```
def add(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x + (-y)
add: (x: Int)Int => Int

scala> def adder = add(100)   // x is bound to 100 in the returned closure
adder: Int => Int

scala> adder(1)
res42: Int = 99
```

Second Method using one arg list followed by another

```
scala> def add2(x:Int)(y:Int) :  Int =  x + y
add2: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> def  adder2 = add2(100)
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method add2;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it 
 as a partially applied function

       def  adder2 = add2(100)
                         ^

scala> def  adder2 = add2(100) _    // Okay, here is the '_'
adder2: Int => Int

scala> adder2(1)                    // Now i can call the curried function
res43: Int = 101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between *method types* and *function types*.  It's a subtle and sometimes confusing difference.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) contains a pretty comprehensive explanation of the differences between method types and function types.  Here's some of the most relevant points for your question:

> A **Function Type** is (roughly) a type of the form `(T1, ..., Tn) => U`, which is a shorthand for the trait `FunctionN` in the standard library.
>
> A **Method Type** is a non-value type. That means there is no value - no object, no instance - with a method type... A method type is a `def` declaration - everything about a `def` except its body.

You can't directly assign a method do a `val`:

```
def foo(x: Int) = x
val myFooVal = foo //does not compile
```

The process of *eta-expansion* can convert a method to a function, which you can assign to a `val`:

```
val myFooVal = foo _
```

[Here](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/) is a blog post that explores eta-expansion a little bit more in depth.

The interesting thing in your example is that you're mixing methods with functions.  This is totally fine, but it might be a part of what's confusing you here:

```
def add(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x + (-y)
```

This is method *that returns a function*, while this:

```
def add2(x:Int)(y:Int) =  x + y
```

Is a pure method, which, as with all methods, can be converted to a function type using eta-expansion:

```
add2 _ //Int => (Int => Int)
add2(2) _ //Int => Int
```

It might be edifying to play around in the REPL to see how Scala treats these types differently:

```
def add(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x + (-y)
//add: (x: Int)Int => Int

def add2(x:Int)(y:Int) =  x + y
//add2: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int
```

Notice how the printout from the REPL differs here.  In the first example, we can see that `add` is a method that returns something of type `Int => Int`, which is a function.  In the second example, the method syntax is preserved through the second argument.